# Oracle Data types and Storage

Tags: oracle11g

I was asked to find out how many bytes does each row in a data base table take, I know that **Date** takes 7 bytes, **TimeStamp** takes 12 bytes, my question is, is there a way to find how many bytes do **Number**, **Number(19,0)** and **VARCHAR2(128 CHAR)** data types take, is there a way to calculate that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50972

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please consult [Oracle Database Concepts documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm#CNCPT89006) and [details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1833). Generally speaking:

- Number: one for length/sign and then Binary Coded Decimal so two digits per byte.
- Varchar2: one for length when less then 240, plus contents. Two for length when more than 240.

Comment: plus content means each char gets 1 byte?

Comment: Yes, approximately. Depends on the character set. For instance us7ascii needs 1 byte per character. Al32utf8 also, but only for the characters in us7ascii. The rest take 2 up to 4 bytes (therefore the 32 bits in al32utf8). And of course ignoring compression, overhead, chaining, indexes, etc.